# how to run an if-else statement on jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the code below.   Now I want to run an if-else statement on it, but it's not working.  Any idea with this?

```
var num1 = $('#id1').val(); 
var num2 = $('#id2').val();

var newVal = (num1+2)*(num2/4);
var nextVal =(num1+4)*(num2/2);
var newArr = new Array();
newArr.push(newVal);
newArr.push(nextVal);

newArr.sort();

if(newArr.get(0)==newVal)
$("body").html("<p>works fine!</p>");
else $("body").html("<p>works awfully!</p>");
```

Comment: Be sure to mention what you are experiencing when something is "not working"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared "Var" with capital V on this line:

```
Var newVal = (num1+2)*(num2/4);
```

Also, access array's elements with [index], instead of .get(index)

Here is edited code:

```
  var num1 = 50;   
  var num2 = 100;

  var newVal = parseInt((num1+2)*(num2/4));
  var nextVal =parseInt((num1+4)*(num2/2));
  var newArr = new Array();
  newArr.push(newVal);
  newArr.push(nextVal);

  newArr = newArr.sort(function(a,b){return a - b});

  if(newArr[0]==newVal)
    $("body").html("<p>works fine!</p>");
  else
    $("body").html("<p>works awfully!</p>");​
```

Comment: I tried all those modifications still no success. Actually, it was working initially but suddenly stopped and so far has been difficult to figure out what is wrong :(

Comment: Try using parseInt() also use === as operator instead of ==

Comment: i tried this if(newArr[0]==parseInt(newVal)) still didn't work :(

Comment: Here is a working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vtVCb/ . I've added a function as a parameter for .sort(), because we need to sort numbers.

Comment: Try if(parseInt(newArr[0])===parseInt(newVal))

Comment: @IvanMarjanovic why? In my jsFiddle I've applied parseInt a few lines above.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `newArr[0]` instead of `newArr.get(0)`

Comment: `sort` method will sort array values as literals instead of numbers. you should provide a custom sort function, like this: `newArr.sort(function(a,b) {return a-b})`

Answer (score 1):

`val` will return a string so you probably have to convert to a number.  You can use the unary plus operator:

```
var num1 = +$('#id1').val(); // Now you get 5 instead of "5" 
var num2 = +$('#id2').val();

//The problem shows up here when you are doing string concatenation instead of addition in the first set of parenthesis
var newVal = (num1+2)*(num2/4);

if(newArr[0]==newVal) // .get is for jQuery collections, just use brackets on an array
```

Comment: everything seems to be working fine except the if-else condition in the jquery :(

Comment: JSFiddle, please.  Or at least the inputs to your script.

Comment: ok, I read there are no if-else statements in Jquery.so, what i want to do is display the if-else conditions. what would happen if the ("body").html() tag is used? would it display the information on a new page or just throw up a pop icon and then display it there?

Comment: It selects `document.body`, parses the HTML you supply, and replaces the contents.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var num1 = 50;   
  var num2 = 100;

  var newVal = (num1+2)*(num2/4);
  var nextVal =(num1+4)*(num2/2);
  var newArr = new Array();
  newArr.push(newVal);
  newArr.push(nextVal);

  newArr.sort();

  if(newArr[0]==newVal)
    $("body").html("<p>works fine!</p>");
  else
    $("body").html("<p>works awfully!</p>");
```

Comment: any idea how to set the textbox in jquery? say if i have something like this : var num1 = 50;  now setting it looks like this : $('#textid').val(num1); will this work?